# Checking the return value of fclose()

Tags: c, file-io

```
    if (fclose(file1) != 0)
{
    printf("Cannot close file\n");
}
```

I learned that the return value for fclose() should always be checked.  I read somewhere that if the file did not close properly, data could be lost. However, i am unsure how a situation like this could occur, or any other situations that are related. What could be done if such a situation happened?

Comment: According to `man fclose` the only error it can return is `EBADF` - "The file descriptor underlying fp is not valid."

Comment: Eugene is right.  Trying to close a file which is already closed - that can happen if we don't enforce strict rules about who opens a file and who closes it.  Ideally, opening and closing should be handled in the same function or module.

Comment: @EugeneSh.You missed the following line: *The `fclose()` function may also fail and set `errno` for any of the errors specified for the routines `close(2)`, `write(2)` or `fflush(3)`.*

Comment: @dbush Ooops. That's the important one.

Comment: I think the larger question is what action can you take if `fclose` fails?

Comment: @dbush Yes, i added that to the question. Thank you.

Comment: a file on a removable device that has been removed by the user? (usb stick, floppy disk,...)